# How to multiply two lists of floats

Tags: python, list

I have two lists: Dir and Vel. 
Each item in each list is a float (list of floats). 
So 1500 elements in Vir (a list), whereby each element is a float. Same for Dir. Values are both NaNs and then real numbers like 1, 1.5, 2, 2.5, etc.
I am trying to compute u = Vel * sin(radians(Dir)). In Matlab it would be simply Vel .* sin(radians(Dir)).

Dir and Vel are both type list. When I open the list, there are 1500 elements of type float. I have tried float(Dir) without any luck. I have math and numpy installed. My specific code is:

```
u = [a * b for a, b in zip(Vel,sin(radians(Dir)))]
```

I am trying to compute the u and v vector shown above but I keep getting the error that a float is required - even though each list contains only floats. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are doing `sin(radians(Dir))` when `Dir` is a list. Try doing the math on `a` and `b` instead.

`[v*(sin(radians(d))) for v,d in zip(vel, dir)]`

Comment: My god this worked. Thank you so much. I just wasted several hours on this 'problem'!

Answer (score 2):

You are probably trying to apply the standard `math.sin` and `math.radians` to an iterable, which is not going to work (they require a scalar). Luckily, NumPy supports vector operations:

```
import numpy as np

vel = np.array([3., 10., 40.])
dir = np.array([30., 0., 90.])

u = vel * np.sin(np.radians(dir))  # element-wise multiplication
print(u)  # prints [ 1.5  0.  40. ]
```